# How to close database connection in php while database file is included?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page say pae1.php has code like

`include_once('db.php');`

in db.php the connection is established

```
$con= mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error());
```

I then simply run a query on page1.php as

```
$delete_s1ql="DELETE FROM tbl_info WHERE id='$id' ";
$res_del=mysql_query($delete_s1ql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Now I want to close my database connection on page1.php.

How can I do this?

Comment: mysql_close() you can use it without changing other things as suggested

Comment: You're using a depreciated `MySQL` API. If this script is for a live website, you should consider using `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Change db.php into this (to make sure the selected database is bound to the resource):

```
$con= mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

In page1.php add this to the end (use the global resource-variable to close the correct connection):

```
mysql_close($con);
```

PS: take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for a better way to connect and talk to your database.

Comment: the $con is not needed, mysql_close page -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

Comment: @MarcoMura Since we do not know the rest of the code surrounding this snippet, we cannot ascertain the fact that this is the only database connection in his code... `mysql_close()` will use the last used resource if the $con is ommitted...

Comment: @MarcoMura Not always true. The `$con` argument is also optional for other `mysql_*` function, but omitting it *may sometimes* lead to inexplicable (for some) behaviour.

Comment: @MarcoMura `if put exactly under the delete it will work fine` - Yes, and results in code otherwise known as 'unmaintainable crap'

Comment: Havelock, never happened for single db applications. But if you say so then let's add the $con link on the query

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
mysql_close($con);
```

MySQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `mysql_close($con);` in pae1.php since include_once also includes the variables defined in db.php

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO... Basically, try using PHP libraries for infrastructure purposes like DB